# Clarification on the concept of "General formulation of the problem of statistical inference" - Wald

Tags: probability, inference, mathematical-statistics

I'm looking for clarification on one part of this definition, but also some feedback on my interpretation of the whole concept. The definition comes from the end of the first chapter of [On the Principles of Statistical Inference](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175196978#toc)

[image]

**Quick clarification**

The part I need clarification on is the line "system of subclasses of the class $\Omega$". Does that mean the same thing as the family of subsets of the set $\Omega$?

I looked on the [wiki on class (set theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) and found the following, however the text from Wald was written in 1942, so I'm not sure if it means the same thing here.

> Outside set theory, the word "class" is sometimes used synonymously with "set". This usage dates from a historical period where classes and sets were not distinguished as they are in modern set-theoretic terminology. Many discussions of "classes" in the 19th century and earlier are really referring to sets, or perhaps to a more ambiguous concept.

I don't have a background in set theory, I understand the elementary concepts of set, subsets and family over a set though. Hope someone here can give me a quick clarification!

**My interpretation**

*I am assuming that here, 'system' means family, 'subclass' means subset and 'class' means set.*

I have started to build a visualization in my head of what this definition means, I will do my best to explain and would appreciate any feedback or refinement to make sure I'm fully grasping this concept.

We start with n random variables $X_{1}...X_{n}$ that have an unknown join probability distribution. If we assume that they are independently distributed each of normal distribution with unit variance, then we can characterize the unknown join probability distribution as $\prod_{i=1}^{n}{F(x)}$ where $F(x)$ defines the normal cdf (in our scenario it is with mean $\mu$ and unit variance)

Therefore, we've refined $\Omega$ to be the set of all possible normal join probability distributions of this form. To make it easier to visualize, let's say we are only dealing with 2 random variables. I'm imagining $\Omega$ as this set of every possible form of the unknown joint probabilities as these surfaces (normal distribution two vars). By every possibly form I mean every possible combination of means $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ that could characterize $\prod_{i=1}^{n}{F(x)}$.

[image: credit to brilliant.org]

Then the 'system' $S$ is the collection of subsets $s$ of $\Omega$; I'm imagining that perhaps each subset $s$ gathers all of the surfaces that have the same mean - in our case we've given our random variables the same unit variance so each subset $s$ would only have one element (or surface). If we relaxed the assumption so that each random variable could have a different variance, then each subset $s$ would have many elements.

The rest of my interpretation more or less follows the given...for each of these subsets $s$, we craft a the hypothesis $H_{s}$ that our unknown $F$ is an element of $s$. Then we collect all of the hypothesis as a set, called $H_{S}$, and our problem is to determine which of the elements of $H_{S}$ should be accepted base on our sample. In our case, the sample could be one realization each of the r.v's $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, i.e. a point in 2-d space, and we try to determine which 'surface' it came from.

I'm fairly certain this captures the specific cases of estimation, simple hypothesis and trilemma that Wald mentions.

[image]

I won't describe them in detail, but briefly the problem of simple hypothesis is that our unknown distribution $F$ belongs to the subset $\omega$ where $\omega$ contains the 'surfaces' of $\Omega$ with mean 0, this is only one surface because we said both random variables had unit variance.

Sorry for the lengthy question, if you've had the patience to read the whole thing, thank you!

How far off am I in my interpretation? I am mostly concerned with the developing the right intuition here - I am certain that my notation and use of definitions is loose.